# Phusion throws undefined method `Struct' for main:Object with delayed_jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, delayed-job

So I have a class that gets loaded and is supposed to be run by delayed_jobs and to get some parameters into the class I have used the Struct trick, this works on development but not on production running rails 3.0.3 and passenger 3. Any one know why?

The error message Im getting from passenger is "undefined method `Struct' for main:Object" and the code is as follows.

```
class HandsetReader < Struct.new(:csv_id)
  def perform
    @csv = CsvFiles.find(csv_id)

    if @csv.external_type == "Customer"
      ..
    else
      ..
    end
end
```

Comment: where is this defined ? I mean the HandsetReader class

Comment: Undefined method Struct? What version of Ruby is this? That should be giving you an uninitialized constant error.

Answer (score -3):

Try `require 'struct'`  as the first line of your source file.

Comment: Struct is in core and does not have to be required.